# Fatal Error JRE Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

my android studio always force close after launch. this error in my project hs_err_pid.log. I have tried searching on google but I haven't found anything that I could relate to.

My Operating system is win 10(64), RAM : 4GB.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000046d25f3, pid=6856, tid=0x0000000000000fe0
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b06) (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b06 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 10261 C1 org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureType(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode; (132 bytes) @ 0x00000000046d25f3 [0x00000000046d22a0+0x353]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000016b05000):  JavaThread "Daemon worker Thread 2" [_thread_in_Java, id=4064, stack(0x0000000018e20000,0x0000000018f20000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x00000001000a2dc0, RBX=0x000000001ee050c8, RCX=0x00000000c1565968, RDX=0x00000000c1565968
RSP=0x0000000018f1ba40, RBP=0x0000000018f1bb58, RSI=0x000000001ee050c8, RDI=0x00000000000001d8
R8 =0x00000000f0cfb798, R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00000000046d22c0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000018f1bb08, R14=0x0000000018f1bb90, R15=0x0000000016b05000
RIP=0x00000000046d25f3, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000018f1ba40)
0x0000000018f1ba40:   00000001002de408 0000000000000001
0x0000000018f1ba50:   0000000016b05000 0000000000000002
0x0000000018f1ba60:   0000000000000002 0000000074325a62
0x0000000018f1ba70:   00000001002de408 0000000016b05000
0x0000000018f1ba80:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x0000000018f1ba90:   000000007480d128 00000000034b7bbc
0x0000000018f1baa0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000002
0x0000000018f1bab0:   0000000017f383c0 00000000742d629d
0x0000000018f1bac0:   0000000018f1c178 00000000f0cfb798
0x0000000018f1bad0:   000000001a5a2ca1 0000000016b05000
0x0000000018f1bae0:   000000001bbb2110 0000000002ca2fad
0x0000000018f1baf0:   0000000018f1bb58 0000000002c87e20
0x0000000018f1bb00:   0000000002c87e20 00000000f0cfb798
0x0000000018f1bb10:   00000000c1565968 0000000018f1bb18
0x0000000018f1bb20:   000000001a5a2cb1 0000000018f1bb90
0x0000000018f1bb30:   000000001a5b07d8 000000001ee084a0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000046d25f3)
0x00000000046d25d3:   12 00 00 00 53 50 e8 02 a2 61 fe 5b 5b 83 fb 00
0x00000000046d25e3:   0f 84 8b 00 00 00 48 bb c8 50 e0 1e 00 00 00 00
0x00000000046d25f3:   41 8b 41 08 48 c1 e0 03 48 3b 83 f0 01 00 00 75
0x00000000046d2603:   0d 48 83 83 f8 01 00 00 01 e9 7f 00 00 00 48 3b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000001000a2dc0 is pointing into metadata
RBX=0x000000001ee050c8 is pointing into metadata
RCX=0x00000000c1565968 is an oop
org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7 
 - klass: 'org/codehaus/groovy/vmplugin/v7/Java7'
RDX=0x00000000c1565968 is an oop
org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7 
 - klass: 'org/codehaus/groovy/vmplugin/v7/Java7'
RSP=0x0000000018f1ba40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016b05000
RBP=0x0000000018f1bb58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016b05000
RSI=0x000000001ee050c8 is pointing into metadata
RDI=0x00000000000001d8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000f0cfb798 is an oop
sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl 
 - klass: 'sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/ParameterizedTypeImpl'
R9 =0x1fffffffffffffff is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000046d22c0 is at entry_point+32 in (nmethod*)0x00000000046d1ed0
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000018f1bb08 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016b05000
R14=0x0000000018f1bb90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016b05000
R15=0x0000000016b05000 is a thread
```

Comment: C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio2.3
rename this file and then start android studio fresh

Comment: @JaydeepPatel what to rename? Folder name?

Comment: rename AndroidStudiox.x.x for new settings

Comment: @JaydeepPatel thanks, for two days my android studio not crash again, i dont know tomorrow lol, how i choose your comment for solve my problem?

Comment: Happy to help :-).
accept my answer if it works. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is look like an settings problem or incomplete installation.
for reintialize settings do following:

> C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio2.3

rename this file and then start android studio fresh

and in technical language follow below link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html